# SQL: How to create a daily view based on different time intervals using SQL logic?

Tags: sql, azure, view, logic

Here is an example:

```
Id|price|Date
1|2|2022-05-21
1|3|2022-06-15
1|2.5|2022-06-19
```

Needs to look like this:

```
Id|Date|price
1|2022-05-21|2
1|2022-05-22|2
1|2022-05-23|2
...
1|2022-06-15|3
1|2022-06-16|3
1|2022-06-17|3
1|2022-06-18|3
1|2022-06-19|2.5
1|2022-06-20|2.5
... 
Until today 
1|2022-08-30|2.5
```

I tried using the lag(price) over (partition by id order by date)
But i can't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Azure, but it looks like you need to use a calendar table, or generate missing dates using a recursive CTE.

To get started with a recursive CTE, you can generate line numbers for each `id` (assuming multiple id values) in the source data ordered by `date`. These rows with row number equal to `1` (with the minimum `date` value for the corresponding `id`) will be used as the starting point for the recursion. Then you can use the `DATEADD` function to generate the row for the next day. To use the `price` values ​​from the original data, you can use a subquery to get the `price` for this new date, and if there is no such value (no row for this `date`), use the previous `price` value from CTE (use the `COALESCE` function for this).

For SQL Server query can look like this

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        date,
        price
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS rn
        FROM tbl
    ) t
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        cte.id,
        DATEADD(d, 1, cte.date),
        COALESCE(
            (SELECT tbl.price 
            FROM tbl 
            WHERE tbl.id = cte.id AND tbl.date = DATEADD(d, 1, cte.date)), 
            cte.price
        )
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, cte.date) <= GETDATE()
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY id, date
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Note that I added `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to make the recursion run through all the steps, since the default value is 100, this is not enough to complete the recursion.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e00594d4ccda7300ec2b139412cf536)*

---

The same approach for MySQL (you need MySQL of version 8.0  to use CTE)

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        date,
        price
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS rn
        FROM tbl
    ) t
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        cte.id,
        DATE_ADD(cte.date, interval 1 day),
        COALESCE(
            (SELECT tbl.price 
            FROM tbl 
            WHERE tbl.id = cte.id AND tbl.date = DATE_ADD(cte.date, interval 1 day)), 
            cte.price
        )
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATE_ADD(cte.date, interval 1 day) <= NOW()
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY id, date
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f439cfb010f12390ecc09dd7b4b2cc6a)*

---

Both queries produces the same results, the only difference is the use of the engine's specific date functions.

---

For MySQL versions below 8.0, you can use a calendar table since you don't have CTE support and can't generate the required date range.

Assuming there is a column in the calendar table to store date values ​​(let's call it `date` for simplicity) you can use the `CROSS JOIN` operator to generate date ranges for the `id` values in your table  that will match existing dates. Then you can use a subquery to get the latest `price` value from the table which is stored for the corresponding `date` or before it.

So the query would be like this

```
SELECT
   d.id,
   d.date,
   (SELECT
        price
    FROM tbl
    WHERE tbl.id = d.id AND tbl.date <= d.date
    ORDER BY tbl.date DESC
    LIMIT 1
    ) price
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.id,
        c.date
    FROM calendar c
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tbl) t
    WHERE c.date BETWEEN (
        SELECT
            MIN(date) min_date
        FROM tbl
        WHERE tbl.id = t.id
    )
    AND NOW()
) d
ORDER BY id, date
```

Using my pseudo-calendar table with `date` values ranging from `2022-05-20` to `2022-05-30` and source data in that range, like so

| id | price | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-05-21 |
| 1 | 3 | 2022-05-25 |
| 1 | 2.5 | 2022-05-28 |
| 2 | 10 | 2022-05-25 |
| 2 | 100 | 2022-05-30 |

the query produces following results

| id | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-21 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-05-22 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-05-23 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-05-24 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-05-25 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-05-26 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-05-27 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-05-28 | 2.5 |
| 1 | 2022-05-29 | 2.5 |
| 1 | 2022-05-30 | 2.5 |
| 2 | 2022-05-25 | 10 |
| 2 | 2022-05-26 | 10 |
| 2 | 2022-05-27 | 10 |
| 2 | 2022-05-28 | 10 |
| 2 | 2022-05-29 | 10 |
| 2 | 2022-05-30 | 100 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b45bd8d30760f0ef904c8df2524b4140)*

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your response.
Sadly, CTE is not supported on  the version I am using.

Comment: I already have another table calendar generated, with all the dates since 2000 until now. Maybe we can link the logic with that table?

Comment: @RazvanGambutan, I've added the query that shows an approach to using a calendar table and doesn't use CTEs or any other window functions.

Comment: thank you! The second solution you provided works!